# Android Firebase SDK with GTM implemented - Recommended events and params can't be processed - Error: Invalid param type for key 'items'

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

**Problem:**

Implemented GTM on Android app. Can't pass items[] array when GTM is present. **When GTM is removed** from the code items[] array is passed correctly.

Already reported here:
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/thread/171816134/android-google-tag-manager-items-cannot-be-arraylist?hl=en
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/thread/126207720/android-send-an-array-event-property?hl=en

**Technical details of implementation:**

GTM version - 18.0.3

Firebase version - 21.3.0

Used Firebase recommended [class reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=android#log_events_3) for e-commerce (recommemded) events and params `com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.Event` `com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.Param`
Code:

```
fun trackCartView(
  currency : String,
  items    : ArrayList<TrackProductItemWithQuantity>,
  value    : Double
) {
  val params = Bundle()
  params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CURRENCY, currency)
  val products = ArrayList(items.map {
    val product = Bundle()
    product.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY5, it.item_category5)
    it.discount?.let {
      product.putDouble(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.DISCOUNT, it)
    }
    product.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_BRAND, it.brand)
    product.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, it.item_id)
    product.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, it.item_name)
    product.putDouble(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.PRICE, it.price)
    product.putInt(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.QUANTITY, it.quantity)
    product
  })

  params.putParcelableArrayList(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEMS, products)

  params.putDouble(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE, value)

  analytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.VIEW_CART, params)
}
```

**Result:**

`Internal error - Function call: __fm_sendFirebaseEvent Invalid param type for key 'items'. Only boolean, double and string types and maps of thereof are supported.`

This is **serious issue** for analytics implementation on mobile apps. Can we expect this to be fixed soon? Or any other details?